# angular download link with function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a list loop in my view and each item of this list has a download link (basically each item is downloadable) now I would like to add download link which comes frm `API` by function but not sure how?!

**Logic**

`API structure`

```
product {
  documents [
    'doc1' => [
      'file' => 'http://....../dddd.zip',
      //etc.  
    ],
   'doc2' => [
      'file' => 'http://....../dddd.zip',
      //etc.  
    ],
  ],
  // 'etc.' =>....
}
```

**Code**

`view`

```
<ion-col size-xl="3" size-lg="4" size-md="4" size-sm="6" size-xs="12">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let doc of product.documents | slice:0:limit" (click)="downloadLink()">
    <ion-label>
      Download
    </ion-label>
    {{doc.download_count | number:'':'en-Us'}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

`controller`

```
downloadLink() {
  // set document file link for download
}
```

> **PS** My files link from API can be accessible with `{{doc.file}}` this
>   gives full URL of file as it comes like that from API, there is no
>   need to add any additional `www....../etc.`
>
> **Note:** In case that I get my documents links will need to loop my
>   `product.documents` in controller as well I guess. In order to get
>   that `doc.file` link.

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use html "a" download attribute

```
<ion-col size-xl="3" size-lg="4" size-md="4" size-sm="6" size-xs="12">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let doc of product.documents | slice:0:limit" (click)="downloadLink()">
    <ion-label>
      <a href="{{ doc.file }}" download>Download</a>
    </ion-label>
    {{doc.download_count | number:'':'en-Us'}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

Or another workaround is to pass the object to downloadlink function

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let doc of product.documents | slice:0:limit" (click)="downloadLink(doc)">
```

In your ts file

```
downloadLink(doc: any) {
   console.log(doc);
   window.open(doc.file);
}
```